# Renaming file in URL (.php file)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a file called `filename-step1.php` and looking to make the url `domain.com/filename/step1` through .htaccess.

My current `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

At the moment, this works fine for removing the `.php` tag from the url. Just need to fix the directories.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your .htaccess rules file into your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! I have added it.

Comment: "this works fine for removing the .php tag" - That doesn't "remove" the `.php` extension, it  "adds" it. You've presumably already removed it in your request (anchor).

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `RewriteRule` to redirect to `$1/$2.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1-$2.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

So, `filename/step1` will trigger the `filename-step1.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I am giving 2 solutions here, please try one at a time only in your .htaccess file. With your shown samples, could you please try following as a Generic rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1-$2.php [NC,L]
```

---

---

OR in case you are looking for specifically url `filename/step1` try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(filename)/(step1)/?$ $1-$2.php [NC,L]
```